# Why do the leagues show more earned reputation than total reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Looking at the reputation leagues on the main stack exchange site, I noticed that some users have supposedly earned more in reputation, say, a month than they have total reputation.

How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe they spent some of it on bounties?

Comment: @mattdm The particular one I notice doesn't have any bounties

Comment: @damnedtruths: Yes, but they may have SPENT some of their own bounty on others.

Comment: @jrista No bounties at all, none spent, none received, nothing. And the difference is not enough to be bounties anyway

Answer (score 2):

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/159222) on the main meta site:

> "total reputation" includes private reputation events, while "month reputation" does not.

So some things like deleted posts / downvotes may impact an individual's total reputation and monthly reputation in different ways.